# Java -- What is the most efficient way to synchronize an ArrayList?

Tags: java, multithreading, data-structures, synchronization, arraylist

My program has an openGL rendering thread and a data modification thread. The rendering thread accesses the data in a gaggle of ArrayLists, while the data modification thread alters, removes, and adds objects to the ArrayLists. The threads update about 60 times per second, and the ArrayList manipuation is the program's bottleneck.  I've tried synch blocks (super slow), CopyOnWriteArrayLists (quite slow), and creating buffer ArrayLists in the rendering thread (lesser of three evils). What's the 'best' way to get maximum efficiency out of concurrent ArrayLists?

Comment: You need to tell more about the algorithm and topology of the "gaggle of ArrayLists".

Comment: Have you considered leveraging `ConcurrentHashMap` or `ConcurrentSkipListMap/Set`?

Comment: have you looked at the java.util.concurrent package as an alternative to sync blocks?

Comment: What kind of data are you accessing/modifying? Perhaps there are more efficient structures than ArrayLists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best mechanism is to do your work in the GL thread and queue operations to be executed. If there is only ever one thread accessing the list, there is no problem.

Comment: Why is it best to migrate the program logic into the gl thread?

Comment: You're mucking with the GL state. All state mucking-about-with should be done in the GL thread. Simple as that.

Comment: I just started programming GL about 3 days ago. I'll read up on GL states. But even when the program was Java Swing, the essence of the problem remains the same, no? I didn't intent for this to be a GL specific question.

Comment: Swing has an EDT -- Event Dispatch Thread. In order to make sure that the Swing state doesn't get messed up, all work is done on this thread. so yes :)

Comment: I know the EDT. What's the GL equiv?

Comment: Depends on the GL implementation, but it *will* have one, somewhere :)

Comment: On Android, you need to get the surface instance, and then 

surface.queueEvent(new Runnable() {
    ....
});

Comment: Or perhaps something to do with http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.Renderer.html

Comment: It looks like they have two methods of execution: one where you insert your own rendering code into a GLSurfaceView which is processed every frame, and another where you can post runnables for execution. Use the first method for your general code, it's more efficient. But for doing stuff from other threads like modifying lists 'owned' by the GL thread, you would post a Runnable. Then, when everything gets evaluated, including the GL update and the posted runnables, nothing will execute at the same time as anything else. It's quite simple.

Answer (score 3):

```
List<YourObject> syncList = Collections.synchronizedList(yourList);
```

Comment: I'm extremely weary about this solution. First of all, the collection must be synchronised manually when the iterator is used, and there may be other problems too. I think this is a problem with program logic.

Comment: This gives you a blanket all-or-nothing solution, where as the question is about trying to achieve higher granularity of locking

Comment: -1 This doesn't answer the question at all. In fact, using Collection.synchronized* is always the cheapest most inefficient and often times incorrect way to synchronize on a collection. Though it can occasionally "get the job done" it is only good to use when the job doesn't really matter.